# Selectors, child and not for color span-parent and a-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am learning Selectors and not.
What I am trying is to PUT the text of the span in color red BUT NOT the text of the link, combining both. It is just to learn.
My HTML code

```
    <div>1
        <p>2
            <span>Here red
                <a>Here NOT red
                </a>
            </span>
            <div>3
            </div>
        </p>
    </div>
```

What I am trying to do with CSS

```
    div p span:not(:nth-child(0)) {
    color: red;
    }

    /* Or */

    div p span:not(a) {
    color: red;
    }
```

Anyone can help me? I do not want to set another rule for A. It is just to learn as I said.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of issues with your page. One is that you had an extra `div` closing tag. Second, the `a` tag defines a hyperlink, so it should have an `href` attribute. Your a tag had no attributes.

Take a look at this snippet

```css
span:not(a) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
 <div>1
   <p>2
     <span>Here red
       <a href="http://www.apple.com">Here NOT red</a>
     </span>
   </div>
   </p>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could just close the span tag before the a tag, and then just select the span element.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes... My problem was with the href missing!